# is_greater_than template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates

Another day, another experiment with template meta-programming that's gone awry.  I'm attempting to make an `is_greater_than` template that will take in two integral values `N` and `M` of type `T`.

```
template<typename T, T N, T M>
struct is_greater_than<void, N, M>;

template<typename T = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::value, T N, T M>
struct is_greater_than<T, N, M>
{
    static const bool value = N > M;
};
```

Try as I might I can't seem to get this to work.  Attempting to compile this yields 112 compiler errors.  I have an ideone fiddle here: http://ideone.com/ch1j7b.

What am I doing wrong here?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First learn basics of class template and their specialization, then come to meta-programming, enable_if and all.

Comment: what's the point ? Why not just use `a > b` ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I'm going to use this to make a more complicated macro that will create a type based on an integer value, but I need this one to work first.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker That's run-time and not compile-time. One point of template meta-programming is to perform some operation at compile-time instead of run-time.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : if something like `is_greater_than<a, b>` is possible, then `a > b` can be calculated at compile time.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I think you're on to something there.  Attempting something; will respond if it worked.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker `a > b` can be precalculated by the compiler, but is not a compile-time expression. You cannot use it in some places where you can use `is_greater_than<T, N, M>::value`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: If `a` and `b` are compile-time constant, then `a>b` is compile-time computation *in practice*.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Yes, but the point of structures like this is to use it in other templates just like `std::is_integral` and `std::enable_if` is used here. You might also want to read more about [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE).

Comment: @Gorpik : can you give an example ? I never encountered (or can imagine) a situation where such a `is_greater_than<a, b>` would be allowed , but not `a > b`. They're really the same thing after all. And yes, I do know and have (limited) experience with template metaprogramming.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I think Joachim did that for me.

Comment: @Gorpik : the SFINAE examples given are about overload resolution. Integer or boolean values (like `a`, `b`, `a > b`) have no impact on overload resolution (only types do), so I don't see how he did. Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker You are right, `a > b` is also a `const` if `a` and `b` are `const` (and if they are not, you cannot use them in `is_greater_than<>`). My mistake there. But `is_greater_than<>` itself is a type that you can pass to a template, while `operator<` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
template<typename T, T N, T M, typename enable = void>
struct is_greater_than;

template<typename T, T N, T M>
struct is_greater_than<T,N,M, 
       typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
{
    static const bool value = N > M;
};

int main()
{
    bool a = is_greater_than<int, 11, 10>::value;

    cout << boolalpha << a << endl;
}
```

Output:

> true

[*Live code*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa39aa0f6b6255b9)

Comment: Works like a charm, and I learned something. :) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

Your usage of `std::enable_if` is wrong, it should be a separate template parameter (possibly unnamed):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, T N, T M,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
struct is_greater_than:
    public std::integral_constant<bool, (N > M)>::type
{
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_greater_than<int, 1, 2>::value
              << is_greater_than<int, 1, 1>::value
              << is_greater_than<int, 2, 1>::value;
}
```

Note that I'm inheriting from`std::integral_constant` here, it'll define the `value` and `type` members for us based in its second argument (parenthesis around `N > M` are required).

Comment: I'm not sure but inheriting from STL types is not a good practice, is it?

Comment: @MM. `integral_constant` is supposed to be inherited from.

Comment: @Simple but, but... it doesn't have virtual destructor! :P

Comment: @jrok neither did `std::unary_function` et al, but they were made to be inherited from, but not to be used polymorphically.

Comment: @juanchopanza I was just sarcastic about the usual argument of purists that are getting a rash if you even mention inheriting from something from `std`.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles fine in VS2010:

```
template<typename T, T M, T N>
struct is_greater_than;

template<typename T = std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value, T >::value, T M = T(), T N = T()>
struct is_greater_than {
    static const bool value = M > N;
};
```

You can test it with:

```
std::cout << is_greater_than<int,4,2>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << is_greater_than<std::string,"a","B">::value << std::endl;
```

Comment: Yes, it was just a quick test in VS2010. You solution is much better.